# Find and replace a block of code in the whole project using NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

For example, the following segment of code inside a method,

```
int size = selectedValues.size();
if (size == 1) {
    deleteSingle();
} else if (size > 1) {
    deleteMultiple();
}
```

is mistakenly repeated at several places and needs to be replaced with the following piece of code doing the same thing.

```
switch (selectedValues.size()) {
    case 1:
        deleteSingle();
        break;
    default:
        deleteMultiple();
}
```

Is there any shortcut for this kind of replacements in the entire project (Java EE) using NetBeans (8.0.2)?

<sub>I tried to apply some regular expressions (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) but the regular expressions did not match, since I am very weak at RegEX.</sub>

Comment: You know that these two code blocks aren't doing the same, right? What about **0**?

Comment: Yes. `else if (size > 1) {` is actually needlessly written. It should have just been `else`.

Comment: So you want to call `deleteMultiple` with an empty collection? ... ok.

Comment: No. This is a story apart. This piece of code is written inside a method in a JSF managed bean which will not be executed, if the collection is `null` or  empty. `deleteMultiple()` will be invoked, when the collection holds more than one item/element.

Comment: Try using (ctrl + R), I only used it to replace single lines, but maybe it also works with multiple line texts.

Comment: @redxef : ctrl + R is used to refactor and rename of variables, methods, classes etc and will not work for replacing a block of statements with another block of statements or something else.

Comment: Well, IntelliJ supports a feature called ["Structural Search and Replace"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace.html) ([Examples](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html)). If Netbeans doesn't has a similar feature, then you can download and use the free version of IntelliJ just for that replacement and delete it after that.

Comment: @Tiny Well, I'm coming from Mac and the shortcut for "Find and replace" is (cmd + R), so, yeah...

Answer (score 0):

Couple of considerations.

If you use the basic wildcards option instead, you run the risk of matching stuff other than your code.  but you could, uncheck those in the search results window before changing.

The refactor menu 'introduce method' function might work, if all your instances are in the same class.

The strategy you were using should be fine, if you have the Regex working.  There are a couple of Netbeans plugins which help you cleanup and debug regex.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/41152/regextester
   and 
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/41152/regextester

But food for though : 
take a look at

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/1529/pmd-s-copy-paste-detector

your core problem is that you have duplicate code, the issue being if it is not correct, its a pain to change.

consider creating a common function for the code that can be called from all the different places.  looking at the code, probably a Util class with a 'static' method.